# C++ slows over time reading 70,000 files

Tags: c++, string, performance, stdvector

I have a program which needs to analyze 100,000 files spread over multiple filesystems.

After processing around 3000 files it starts to slow down. I ran it through gprof, but since the slow down doesn't kick in until 30-60 seconds into the analysis, I don't think it tells me much.

How would I track down the cause? `top` doesn't show high CPU and the process memory does not increase over time, so I/O?

At top level, we have:

```
scanner.init(); // build a std::vector<std::string> of pathnames.
scanner.scan(); // analyze those files
```

Now, init() completes in 1 second.  It populates the vector with 70,000 actual filenames and 30,000 symbolic links.

scan() traverses the entries in the vector, looks at the file names, reads the contents (say 1KB of text), and builds a "segment list" [1]

I've read conflicting views on the evils of using std::strings, especially passing them as arguments. All the functions pass &references for both std::strings, structures, etc.

But it does use a lot of string processing to parse filenames, extract substrings and search for substrings. (and if they were evil, the program should be *always slow*, not just slow down after a while.

Could that be a reason for slowing down over time?

The algorithm is very straightforward and doesn't have any `new` / `delete` operators...

Abbreviated, scan():

```
while (tsFile != mFileMap.end())
{
    curFileInfo.filePath = tsFile->second;

    mpUtils->parseDateTimeString(tsFile->first, curFileInfo.start);

    // Ignore files too small
    size_t fs = mpFileActions->fileSize(curFileInfo.filePath);
    mDvStorInfo.tsSizeBytes += fs;

    if (fileNum++ % 200 == 0)
    {
        usleep(LONGNAPUSEC); // long nap to give others a turn
    }

    // collect file information
    curFileInfo.locked    = isLocked(curFileInfo.filePath);
    curFileInfo.sizeBytes = mpFileActions->fileSize(curFileInfo.filePath);
    getTsRateAndPktSize(curFileInfo.filePath, curFileInfo.rateBps, curFileInfo.pktSize);
    getServiceIdList(curFileInfo.filePath, curFileInfo.svcIdList);

    std::string fileBasePath;
    fileBasePath = mpUtils->strReplace(".ts",     "", curFileInfo.filePath.c_str());
    fileBasePath = mpUtils->strReplace(".lockts", "", fileBasePath.c_str()); // chained replace

    // Extract the last part of the filename, ie. /mnt/das.b/20160327.104200.to.20160327.104400
    getFileEndTimeAndDuration(fileBasePath, curFileInfo);

    // Update machine info for both actual ts duration and span including gaps
    mDvStorInfo.tsDurationSec     += curFileInfo.durSec;

    if (!firstTime)
    {
        // beef is here.
        if (hasGap(curFileInfo, prevFileInfo)           ||
            lockChanged(curFileInfo, prevFileInfo)      ||
            svcIdListChanged(curFileInfo, prevFileInfo) ||
            lastTsFile(tsFile))
        {
            // This current file differs from those before it so
            // close off previous segment and push to list

            curSegInfo.prevFileStart = curFileInfo.start;

            mSegmentList.push_back(curSegInfo);

            prevFileInfo = curFileInfo;  // do this before resetting everything!

            // initialize the new segment
            resetSegmentInfo(curSegInfo);
            copyValues(curSegInfo, curFileInfo);
            resetFileInfo(curFileInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            // still running. Update current segment info
            curSegInfo.durSec       += curFileInfo.durSec;
            curSegInfo.sizeBytes    += curFileInfo.sizeBytes;
            curSegInfo.end           = curFileInfo.end;
            curSegInfo.prevFileStart = prevFileInfo.start;

            prevFileInfo = curFileInfo;
        }
    }
    else // first time
    {
        firstTime = false;
        prevFileInfo = curFileInfo;
        copyValues(curSegInfo, curFileInfo);
        resetFileInfo(curFileInfo);
    }

    ++tsFile;
}
```

where:
`curFileInfo/prevFileInfo` is a plain struct. The other functions do string processing, returning a &reference to std::strings

`fileSize` is calculated by calling `stat()`
`getServiceIdList` opens the file with `fopen`, reads each line and closes the file.

**UPDATE**

Removing the push_back to the container did not change the performance at all.  However, rewriting to use C functions (eg. strstr(), strcpy() etc) now shows constant performance.

Culprit was the std::strings – despite passing as &refs, I guess too many construct/destroy/copy.

[1] the file names are named by YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS date/time, eg 20160612.093200. The purpose of the program is to look for time gaps within the *names* of the 70,000 files and build a list of contiguous time segments.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe things slow down when you run out of actual RAM and start using swap file.

Comment: Thanks.  The segmentList (std::vector of structs is really small, 10-20 entries only). So what would use the RAM?  Does memory for std::strings not get reused?  All files are on the local machine.

Comment: Your algorithm itself may not have new/delete, but all STL containers store their contents on the heap.  `vector` can be particularly troublesome as it has to allocate contiguous memory for its contents.  See my Answer below.

Comment: May be its your disk operations which is slowing down. You should lookout for all the stats given by `top`, `iostat`, `vmstat` etc. Are you accessing the files over NFS or any other Networked file system ?

Comment: Another excellent utility is `strace`. Have saved me countless number of times. You can run it when you start seeing the slowdown and figure out which operations are being executed at that point of time.

Comment: No NFS. Files are stored across 10 RAID partitions.  Plus, given the list of 70,000 filenames, we are only opening one file at a time to inspect it...

Comment: show me the code that closes the file and releases all resources used when accessing it, and I'll show you where the problem is. You have a lot of pointer-controlled objects in this code. I think you've forgotten to delete something.

Comment: @Danny You can profile this performance problem with gdb. Run the program from under gdb and let it get to point of significant slowdown. Then interrupt the program, briefly look at the stack trace and continue. Repeat several times. If there is an obvious bottleneck, it should show up soon.

Comment: I suggest writing the program in a language that does GC like Java or C#. This way you won't run into heap fragmentation issues from allocating too many strings. Of course, you can do it in C++, but you might have to write your own memory allocator. Great fun!

Answer (score 1):

This could be a heap fragmentation issue.  Over time, the heap can turn into Swiss cheese making it much harder for the memory manager to allocate blocks, and potentially forcing swap even if there is free RAM because there aren't any large-enough contiguous free blocks.  [Here's an MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366750(v=vs.85).aspx) about heap fragmentation.

You mentioned using `std::vector` which guarantees contiguous memory and therefore can be a major culprit in heap fragmentation, as it must free and reallocate each time the collection grows beyond a boundary.  If you don't require the contiguous guarantee, you might try a different container.

Comment: Thanks.  Before the loop I resized the container to 1000 entries, figuring that's more than enough given it will contain less than 50 entries. I suspect more to do with passing std::strings around, using substr(), find(), or perhaps file I/O.  I just don't know how to track it down. But.... If it is the wrong container, what container do you suggest?

Comment: BTW, system is Linux Centos 6.6 32-bit 3.10 kernel

Comment: Which container you use depends on what features you need.  `vector` provides O(1) index-based retrieval at the cost of more expensive insertion.  `list` has better insertion performance at the cost of O(n) retrieval.  `deque` is typically implemented as a BST, providing O(log n) search and retrieval performance.

Comment: Given that your lists are typically fairly short, the O(n) aspects of `list` may be reasonable for your application, if it cuts down on memory fragmentation (likely, as the list contents are constant size).

Comment: The string operations could also be contributing to heap fragmentation (which, unfortunately, is very hard to measure objectively).  Since `std::string` is also a variable-size container, it probably uses the heap for storage.

Comment: Been playing around: moving to char arrays and replacing mktime sped things up a lot.  But still slows down over time.  There are three containers - see the edited post above - would list be right for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

> the file names are named by YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS date/time, eg 20160612.093200. The purpose of the program is to look for time gaps within the names of the 70,000 files and build a list of contiguous time segments

Comparing strings is slow; O(N). Comparing integers is fast; O(1). Rather than storing the filenames as strings, consider storing them as integers (or pairs of integers).

And I strongly suggest that you use hash maps, if possible. See std::unordered_set and std::unordered_map. These will greatly cut down on the number of comparisons.

> Removing the push_back to the container did not change the performance at all. However, rewriting to use C functions (eg. strstr(), strcpy() etc) now shows constant performance.

`std::set<char*>` is sorting pointer addresses, not the strings that they contain.

And don't forget to `std::move` your strings to cut down on allocations.

Comment: fileList, the list path names is std::set<std::string>, not char * so the paths themselves should be sorted. By "moving to C strings" I meant doing as few operations & comparisons as possible with std::strings.  So strcmp(s1, s2) instead of s1 == s2, sprintf(s, "%s.%s - %s", s1, s2, s3) instead of s = s1 + "." s2 + " - " ... and the like

Comment: Storing as integers is a really interesting idea.  I'll check it out.  But the comparison speed of strings vs integers would not explain it getting slower *over time*.  Whether O(n) or O(1), the speed would be constant, not hit a dead crawl after running for 2-3 hours.